# Pure CSS tab menu active tab

Tags: html, css

I'm using this:
http://webdesignerhut.com/create-pure-css-tabs/

And are looking for a way to make sure that the tabs are marked with another colour once active. Tried the following but without any success.

```
[id^=tab]:checked ~ [id^=label]  {
    background: #08C;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: There is `.tabs [id^="tab"]:checked + label`, not the thing you wrote.

Answer (score 3):

to make active on current tab, the following might be.

```css
.tabs li.current {
    background: red;
    color: #fff;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Working CSS-only highlighted/hover tabs

I recently solved a similar issue, with more complete highlighting and hover. Here's [a demo](https://daveeveritt.github.io/css-sibling-tabs/) and the [GitHub repo](https://daveeveritt.github.io/css-sibling-tabs/).

These CSS-only tabs also have *optional* JavaScript jump links within each tab’s content. Using naming/numbering conventions the code is scalable (as many or few tabs as you need, etc.).